# How to serve files and html directly from a WCF-service similar to an ASHX-handler?

Tags: wcf, ashx, fileserver

Im writing an install and update-server for an intranet-application and I want the user to be able to install the app directly from a url such as: http://domain.local/myapp/install.exe where this request is handled by my service.

I also would like to be able to serve some basic HTML on for instance http://domain.local/myapp/status.html which is generated on the fly by my WCF-service.

Is this possible? Im using a self-hosted WS-binding WCF-service with .NET4/VS2010 on WS2008R2.

Comment: Why a WCF Service? I can't quite get my head around why you want to do it this way instead of just having some files on a website on your domain...

Comment: Well the service is there for a lot of other things as well and I figured it would be nice to serve the files from this service as well. Also, Im going to zip only the files needed for a particular clients request and I need logic doing this before delivering the stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ive found the solution! WebGet in System.ServiceModel.Web. I had to change the project target from .NET 4 Client to .NET 4 for the System.ServiceModel.Web.dll to turn up in "add reference"